# How to pass a message to open a window using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, message

I'm building an application using C#/WCF. There will be a main form project is essentially the thing that connects all the other projects (DLLs) and the DLLs are not aware or allowed to reference each other. However in one DLL, say the patient dll, there is a form with a button and when that button is clicked it needs to open a form in a different dll say the rx dll but the two DLL's can't reference each other they are only connected via the main form.

So I was wondering if it's possible to accomplish a task like that and if so how to go about it. I would prefer not to use a message queue or send message if possible.

Thanks for any advice or help.

Comment: So you are saying that your dlls musn't have references to each other but can have service references to each other and still live in the same application running on client machine? Why? Have a fun with such architecture ...

Comment: @Ladislav This is actually quite common with C#'s component centric patterns. The [observer pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx) is especially useful when managing larger projects where certain components are used in different configurations and helps separate the UI from the program logic.

Comment: @Tamschi: Yes Observer pattern - but you will not implement it as remote calls.

Comment: Wait a sec, this is strange... @Nicole: Are you using *WCF* (Windows Communication Foundation) for WinForms-"Forms" that show up on different PCs or *WPF* (Windows Presentation Foundation) with XAML-"Windows" on the same computer?

Comment: @Tamschi my main form and DLLs are Windows Form Applications/the client applications and then I have a host application and a wcf service project at least that's what it is right now. I'm completely new to WCF and the WCF service actually does nothing right now and I may not use it but it's just an idea we are thinking about and I added it in case there was a way to do it through the wcf service.

Comment: Ah, now I understand... WCF is used for network applications, so it's not that useful here afaik. Are the .dlls all loaded into the same process or are you running the .exe more than once and load one .dll each?

Comment: The dlls are all loaded into the same process

Comment: In that case, the observer pattern from my answer is the easiest way to do this. It would be best if you create the button form in a central place, a static class with methods for each form for example, and link the event from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link the forms with an event:

Add this to the form with the button:

```
  public event Action OpenOtherFormClick;

  button_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) //Link to the button's Click event...
  {
      if (OpenOtherFormClick != null) { OpenOtherFormClick()}
  }
```

Add this to the main project:

```
  instanceOfFormWithButton.OpenOtherFormClick += () =>
  {
      //Open other form, e.g.
      new OtherForm().Show();
      //or
      new OtherForm().ShowDialog();
      //or, with factory class:
      FormFactory.ShowOtherForm();
  };
```

alternatively:

```
  instanceOfFormWithButton.OpenOtherFormClick += FormFactory.ShowOtherForm;
```

The factory has the advantage that you can restrict certain forms to a single instance, for example to show a detail form only once and only focus it if it's already open.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I truly understand your question, but you might take a look at [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com). 
However you can use WCF for interprocess communication (net.pipe), it's not a good practice.